# Added to autoload paths but not loaded

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am using Rails 5.1.6 on AWS EC2 t2.micro.

I have a file, say `lib/foo/bar.rb`, where the class

```
class Foo::Bar
end
```

is defined. I added

```
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)
```

to `config/application.rb`, but when I check the constant `Foo::Bar` is loaded from `rails console`, it raises the `uninitialized constant Foo::Bar` Name error.

So, I added lines

```
puts "CONFIG ROOT IS #{config.root};"
puts "AUTOLOAD PATHS ARE #{config.autoload_paths};"
```

at the end of `config/application.rb` in order to see if they are correctly set, and they are right.

Then, I tried `require './lib/foo/bar.rb'; Foo::Bar` in `rails console`, and it is also OK.

The attempts at (local) docker are also good.

What is the problem? Why the constants in `lib` are not loaded?

Comment: It's been a while i did some RoR - but i'm pretty sure that autoload relies on proper nesting, and `class Foo::Bar` is not the same as a `class Bar` within a `module Foo`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
module Foo
  class Bar
  end
end
```

https://dan.chak.org/enterprise-rails/chapter-3-organizing-with-modules/

Comment: I tried to see the organization of classes / modules in rails, and I got it. Thanks!